# Why am I getting a duplicate addition to a string when I override it?

Tags: angular, duplicates

My goal: Call function in a service from component which will return me a string array.

I get an array in the first time that is ok. such as:
http://localhost:4200/assets/images/hardwoods/american_white_oak.png

But when I browse to another page and get again to the same page I get the array with an addition:
http://localhost:4200/assets/images/hardwoods/american_white_oak.png.png
*(Duplicate ".png").*

I don't understand why is the array images in the component is not overridden every time I change a page and why if it's not overriden - why only ".png" string is added to it?

**Short Explenation about this part of code:**
I am calling a function in a service. This function is:
1. creating a new string array, Assign an array from an object in a model to it. The object is created by a constructor inside the service.
2. running a for loop on it and inside:
   Does some split/join.
   To lowecase
   Add a string to it from left and right.
   Exit the for loop.
3. returning the modified array.

**Html file of the component**

```
<ngb-carousel #carousel interval="3000" [pauseOnHover]="pauseOnHover" (slide)="onSlide($event)">
<ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let img of images; index as i">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>{{imageNames[i]}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
    <img [src]="img" alt="img">
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**TS of the component**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbCarousel, NgbSlideEvent, NgbSlideEventSource } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ImageService } from 'src/app/services/image.service';
import { from } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-hardwood-heb',
  templateUrl: './hardwood-heb.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hardwood-heb.component.css'],

})
export class HardwoodHebComponent implements OnInit {

  public images: string[] = new Array<string>();
  public imageNames: string[] = new Array<string>();
  unpauseOnArrow: boolean = false;
  paused: boolean = false;
  pauseOnHover: boolean = true;

  constructor(private imageService: ImageService) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.images=[];
    this.imageNames = this.imageService.getImageName();
    this.images = this.imageService.getHardwoodImagesPath();
    this.images.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element);
    });

  }




  @ViewChild('carousel', { static: true }) carousel: NgbCarousel;

  togglePaused() {
    if (this.paused) {
      this.carousel.cycle();
    } else {
      this.carousel.pause();
    }
    this.paused = !this.paused;

  }

  onSlide(slideEvent: NgbSlideEvent) {
    if (this.unpauseOnArrow && slideEvent.paused &&
      (slideEvent.source == NgbSlideEventSource.ARROW_LEFT || slideEvent.source == NgbSlideEventSource.ARROW_RIGHT)) {
      this.togglePaused();
    }
    if (!slideEvent.paused && slideEvent.source == NgbSlideEventSource.INDICATOR) {
      this.togglePaused();
    }
  }

}
```

**Model**

```
export class Hardwood {
    public readonly name: Array<string> = ['אגוז אפריקאי','אגוז אמריקאי','אורן קרולינה','אורן קליר','אלון אדום אמריקאי',
    'אלון לבן אמריקאי','אלון אירופאי','בוק מוקצע','מייפל הארד','ספלי מהגוני','פופלר','דובדבן \ שרי','אשה'];
    // Altname uses also for path name!
    public readonly altName: Array<string> =['African Black Ofram','American Walnut','American Southern yellow pine','American Duglas fir','American Red Oak',
    'American White Oak','European Oak','European Beechwood','American Hard Maple','African Mahagoni Sapelli','American Yellow Poplar','American Cherry','American White Ash'];


}
```

**Service**

```
import { Hardwood } from 'src/app/models/hardwood';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImageService {

  constructor(private hardwoods:Hardwood) { }

  public getHardwoodImagesPath():string[]{
    let str: string[] = this.hardwoods.altName;
    for ( var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ){
      str[i] = str[i].split(' ').join('_');
      str[i] = str[i].toLocaleLowerCase();
      str[i] = `../../../assets/images/hardwoods/${str[i]}.png`;
    }
    return str;
  }

  public getImageName():string[]{
    return this.hardwoods.name; 
  }
}
```

Comment: localhost URL do not work here ;)

Comment: make it this.imageNames also empty array onInIt (this.imageNames = [])

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying your original array.

The simplest fix you can make is to take a copy of the hardwoods array using `slice`. This will make a copy of the array that you can safely work with without modifying the original.

```js
public getHardwoodImagesPath():string[]{
  const str: string[] = this.hardwoods.altName.slice();
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str[i] = str[i].split(' ').join('_');
    str[i] = str[i].toLocaleLowerCase();
    str[i] = `../../../assets/images/hardwoods/${str[i]}.png`;
  }
  return str;
}
```

### The reason why

When you do this:

```js
const str: string[] = this.hardwoods.altName;
```

You are only copying the reference to the original array. It's no different to working with the original array directly. So when you do this:

```js
str[i] = str[i].split(' ').join('_');
```

You are actually updating the `i`th entry in the original array.

### Using `map`

You could improve this by combining the loop and the mapping into one function by using the array function `map`.

```js
public getHardwoodImagesPath():string[]{
  const path = '../../../assets/images/hardwoods/';
  return this.hardwoods.altName.
    .map(x => `${path}${x.replace(/ /g, '_').toLowerCase()}.png`);
}
```

This is combining the loop, the string replacement, and a new array. It is far more efficient that my first answer - I just wanted to highlight the issue rather than get distracted by other improvements.

Comment: I used a different solution but you helped me to understand my mistake!

Thank you so much for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Kurt Hamilton helped me to understand my mistake. So I did what I learned to do (different way). Now all works great.

```
  public getHardwoodImagesPath():string[]{
    let str: string[] = new Array<string>();  // Declared a new array
    for ( var i = 0; i < this.hardwoods.altName.length; i++ ){
      str[i]= this.hardwoods.altName[i]; // Get the value only..
      str[i] = str[i].split(' ').join('_');
      str[i] = str[i].toLocaleLowerCase();
      str[i] = `../../../assets/images/hardwoods/${str[i]}.png`;
    }
    return str;
  }
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same! I've added an alternative solution to my answer that is more efficient than either of these.